# Show an operator on $L^2$ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be the complex Lebesgue space $L^2(0,1)$. Let $T:X\to X$ be

$(Tf)(x)=x\int_0^1 \int_0^r f(s)\ ds\ dr-\int_0^x\int_0^r f(s)\ ds\ dr$

Prove that $T$ is compact.

Given a bounded sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $X$, we want to show $\{Tf_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence.

I have shown that $|Tf(x)|\leq 2\lVert f \rVert$. Hence $\lVert Tf_n \rVert \leq 2 \lVert f_n \rVert$. Since $\{f_n\}$ is bounded, then $\{Tf_n\}$ is bounded. Hence there is a weakly convergent subsequence $\{Tf_{n_k}\}$. Then I don't know how to go from weakly convergent to strong convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $S:L^2[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ given by
$$
S(f) := \int_0^1\int_0^rf(s)dsdr = \int_0^1\int_0^1\chi_{[0,r]}f(s)dsdr
$$
Then
$$
|S(f)| \leq \int_0^1\left| \int_0^1 \chi_{[0,r]}f(s)ds\right|dr \leq \int_0^1\|\chi_{[0,r]}\|_2\|f\|_2dr = \|f\|_2\int_0^1rdr = \frac{\|f\|_2}{2}
$$
So $S$ is a bounded linear functional, so the operator $\widetilde{S} : L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$ given by
$$
\widetilde{S}(f)(x) = S(f)x
$$
is a finite rank bounded operator, hence compact.

Now consider $V:L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$ given by
$$
V(f)(x) = \int_0^x\int_0^r f(s)dsdr = \int_0^1\int_0^1k(s,r)f(s)dsdr
$$
where
$$
k(x,y) = \begin{cases}
1 &: 0\leq x\leq y \\
0 &: \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, $V$ is an example of a [Hilbert-Schmidt operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator), and is hence compact. Thus, $T$ is the difference of two compact operators, which is compact.

Comment: Why $\tilde{S}$ is finite rank? I see that it is bounded, but why the rangle of $\tilde{S}$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: It's range is the one dimensional space spanned by $g(x)=x$.